# Ionic 2 Camera does not display Photo Library option

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, ionic2, photolibrary, ionic-native

In Ionic 2 I have to use separate actions for Camera and Photo Library. 
Is there a way when I open Camera, I can go to Photos from inside like I can do in other apps like Whatsapp.

Comment: Instead you can prompt user to select camera or gallery.